# Getting a compass point from 140°

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript converts degrees to a compass point, e.g. `convert.toCompass(140)` gets `140° -> SE`.

I can't help but think: is there a more concise way to do this?

```
var convert = {
    toCompass: function(degrees)
    {
        if(degrees >= 0 && degrees <= 11.25)
        {
            return 'N';
        }

        else if(degrees > 11.25 && degrees <= 33.75)
        {
            return 'NNE';
        }

        else if(degrees > 33.75 && degrees <= 56.25)
        {
            return 'NE';
        }

        else if(degrees > 56.25 && degrees <= 78.75)
        {
            return 'ENE';
        }

        else if(degrees > 78.75 && degrees <= 101.25)
        {
            return 'E';
        }

        else if(degrees > 101.25 && degrees <= 123.75)
        {
            return 'ESE';
        }

        else if(degrees > 123.75 && degrees <= 146.25)
        {
            return 'SE';
        }

        else if(degrees > 146.25 && degrees <= 168.75)
        {
            return 'SSE';
        }

        else if(degrees > 168.75 && degrees <= 191.25)
        {
            return 'S';
        }

        else if(degrees > 191.25 && degrees <= 213.75)
        {
            return 'SSW';
        }

        else if(degrees > 213.75 && degrees <= 236.25)
        {
            return 'SW';
        }

        else if(degrees > 236.25 && degrees <= 258.75)
        {
            return 'WSW';
        }

        else if(degrees > 258.75 && degrees <= 281.25)
        {
            return 'W';
        }

        else if(degrees > 281.25 && degrees <= 303.75)
        {
            return 'WNW';
        }

        else if(degrees > 303.75 && degrees <= 326.25)
        {
            return 'NW';
        }

        else if(degrees > 326.25 && degrees <= 348.75)
        {
            return 'NNW';
        }

        else if(degrees > 348.75 && degrees <= 360)
        {
            return 'N';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THis question is very similar to another question here. There is a fair amount of discussion on that other question whihc may be useful to you too: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36744/find-number-matching-range

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By looking at values in your series of `if`'s, you can make an array (`[]`), then calculate which index to pick:

```
var convert = {
    toCompass: function(degrees)
    {
        return ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW', 'N'][Math.round(degrees / 11.25 / 2)];
    }
}

alert(convert.toCompass(140));      // SE
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dMRL5/4/)

Comment: I'd throw in a `% 360` to be defensive.